# nhibernate + Automapper and many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, automapper

```
public class Technology : EntityBase
{
    [NotNullNotEmpty]
    [Length(ColumnMetadata.LongTextLength)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TechnologyTechCategories> TechCategories { get; set; }
}

public class TechnologyTechCategories : EntityBase
{
    [NotNull]
    public virtual Technology Technology { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public virtual TechCategory TechCategory { get; set; }
}

public class TechCategory : ReferenceBase
{
}

public class TechDetailModel
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tech Categories")]
    [Required]
    public int[] TechCategories { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

These are the classes i have above. So on bind to the controller i ignore the collection of categories for the multiselect dropdown list. But i cant get auto mapper to initialize the IList to the int[] TechCategories. Can someone help with how the mapping should be put together??

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Technology, TechDetailModel>()
                .ForMember(c => c.Categories, option => option.Ignore())
                .ReverseMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to AutoMap a complex type to a simple type here i.e. IList => int[]

I'm assuming EntityBase has some for of identity property e.g. Id

So the following mapping may work for you:

```
           Mapper.CreateMap<Technology, TechDetailModel>()
            .ForMember(c => c.Categories, option => option.Ignore())
            .ForMember(c => c.TechCategories, option => option.MapFrom(src => src.TechnologyTechCategories.Select(p => p.TechCategory.Id)));
```

Given the complex to simple mapping you won't be able to use ReverseMap here.

To simplify the mapping (and your object model) it may be worth looking at changing the many-to-many mapping you have. Do you actually need that 'joining' class. If you specify the IList on both classes, Technology and TechCategory, FluentNHibernate automapping (assuming you are using this) will create the join table for you.